# Assigning values to String class without creating new instance

Tags: java, string

Excuse me if this question is already asked or if its very old.

String is a Class. We are able to assign the value to String without creating new instance object.

like `String someString = "Value";`

How this is working without creating instance for String? Is it possible to create user defined class to assign values directly without creating new object?

Comment: I think you mean, "like `String something = "Value";`"

Comment: String = "Value"; won't work :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this [interesting article](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J3d_String.html):

> **String is Really Special**
>
> The designers of Java decided to retain primitive types in an
>   object-oriented language, instead of making everything an object, so
>   as to improve the performance of the language. Primitives are stored
>   in the call stack, which require less storage spaces and are cheaper
>   to manipulate. On the other hand, objects are stored in the program
>   heap, which require complex memory management and more storage spaces.
>   For performance reason, **Java's String is designed to be in between a
>   primitive and a class**.

---

Also:

> Java has provided a special mechanism for keeping the String literals
>   - in a so-called string common pool..

When you do:

```
String myStr1 = "Hello";
String myStr2 = "Hello";
```

Then

`myStr1 == myStr2` is **true**, because they're both stored in the *pool* (Read the article).

But if you construct a new *String object*:

```
String myStr1 = new String("Hello");
String myStr2 = new String("Hello");
```

Then the references are **not** equal.

I highly recommend to visit the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5). It says that *Strings* are treated in a different way, just like that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "abc";
```

is equivalent to:

```
 char data[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
 or
String str = new String(data);
```

For user defined classes, you have to create an object. 
Refer to docs please for more information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Strings are a special case. The `String` literals are created in `the string pool`. After a string is added in the pool, if another with the same value will be declared, the reference will point to the same string in the pool.

And to answer your question, you cannot create user defined classes and not use `new`. Only if you use only static methods and fields on that class and then you use
`ClassName.StaticFieldOrMethod`.

Answer (score 0):

To know more about how String class works refer

http://java.dzone.com/articles/string-memory-internals

Answer (score 0):

Let us try to understand this with a simple program;

```js
package program;

public class TempList {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String stringWithoutNew = "Test";
    String stringWithoutNew_temp = "Test";

    String stringWithNew = new String("Test");
    String stringWithNew_temp = new String("Test");

    if (stringWithoutNew == stringWithoutNew_temp) {
      System.out.println("This works !!");
    }

    if (stringWithoutNew == stringWithNew) {
      System.out.println("This doesn't work !!");
    }

    if (stringWithNew == stringWithNew_temp) {
      System.out.println("This doesn't work either !!");
    }

  }

}
```